# Java Scanner nextInt() asking for input twice - Asking me to enter the age twice

Tags: java, methods

I have written the following simple program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Person{

    String Name;

    int RetirementVarsha()
    {
        final Scanner EnterNum = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter your age");
        int age = EnterNum.nextInt();

        int rage = 60-age;
        return rage;    
    }



}
public class RetirementAge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Person stats = new Person();

        //Calls method
        int calc = stats.RetirementVarsha();
        System.out.println("Years left for retirement is "+stats.RetirementVarsha());

    }

}
```

When I run this program, it is asking me to enter the age twice. I have seen lot of questions. None of them helped me to address the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling the `RetirementVarsha` method twice, so it reads 2 numbers.
Btw, variable names in java should start with a lowercase letter (same for the methods).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method *RetirementVarsha* two times.

```
 int calc = stats.RetirementVarsha();

 System.out.println("Years left for retirement is "+stats.RetirementVarsha());
```

Try changing your print statement to System.out.println("Years left for retirement is "+calc);

Answer (score 1):

Delete  `int calc = stats.RetirementVarsha();`
 and it should only run once.

you are currently  calling the retirement varsha method twice.